# Angular 2 | *ngFor Loop create new arraylist upon execution

Tags: angular, ngfor

How can i change the index of my loop back to zero when i use same array?

in my ts file

```
data = [{name: 'A', group: 'one'},{name: 'B', group: 'one'},{name: 'C', group: 'two'},{name: 'D', group: 'two'},{name: 'E', group: 'two'}];
```

in my html file

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let apidata of data; let i = index">
   <span *ngIf="apidata.group == 'one'">{{apidata.name}} | {{i}}
<ng-container>

<ng-container *ngFor="let apidata of data; let i = index">
   <span *ngIf="apidata.group == 'two'">{{apidata.name}} | {{i}}
<ng-container>
```

i want to display something like this. as you can see it reset back my index when being passed to a new ng-container

```
<span>A | 1</span>
<span>B | 2</span>
<span>C | 1</span>
<span>D | 2</span>
<span>E | 3</span>
```

so far i always get this actual result

```
<span>A | 1</span>
<span>B | 2</span>
<span>C | 3</span>
<span>D | 4</span>
<span>E | 5</span>
```

Comment: what is the logic of the expected result?

Comment: theres no logic yet in my current code sir, i try to set my `i` into `i = 0;` but its not working so far.

Comment: first index of ngFor is 0 not 1, its by design

Comment: @HDJEMAI yes as you can see in my result it display all the all data with corresponding number 1,2,3,4,5.. but i want to know how can i reset back my array when it is being used on another div tags. like my sample above. i want every data (array) to reset when being called like [div1 - 1,2], [div2 1,2,3]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved simply using the below logic

**1) Below code in component**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public data = [{name: 'A', group: 'one'},{name: 'C', group: 'two'},{name: 'B', group: 'one'},{name: 'D', group: 'two'},{name: 'E', group: 'two'}];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this.groupByData(this.data);
  }

  private groupByData(data): any {
    const groups = ['one', 'two'];
    return data.sort((item1, item2) => {
      if (item1.group === item2.group) {
        return 0;
      } else if (groups.indexOf(item1.group) < groups.indexOf(item2.group)) {
        return -1;
      } else {
        return 1;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**2) Below in template**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let apidata of data; let i = index">
  <span>{{apidata.name}} | {{i + 1}}</span>
</ng-container>
```